# MixMonitor - How to use lame to convert and then remove the source file?

Tags: asterisk, agi

How can I remove the source wav file after the call is finished? If I have to use AGI can I have an example script?

This is how I'm using MixMonitor
    exten => s,n,MixMonitor(${source_file}.wav,W(1),lame -V3 ${source_file}.wav ${mp3_from_source}.mp3)

Fails because it is deleted before the conversion.
    exten => h,n,System(rm ${source_file}.wav)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
exten => s,n,MixMonitor(${source_file}.wav,W(1),lame -V3 ${source_file}.wav ${mp3_from_source}.mp3 && rm ${source_file}.wav)
```

and skip the call in `h`?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What didn't work? Any error messages?

Comment: It deletes the .wav file before lame has converted it to mp3.

Comment: Hmm, the && should prevent the second command from running until the first is completed. Can you try running it manually and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you need to stop being creative.  Just exec the system level calls as separate dial plan lines.  One line for mixmonitor, one line for lame, verify the return value of lame, then delete.  This is what I do in my applications, and it works perfect.  You don't need to combine every step of the conversion process into a single dialplan line.

I use this command line:

```
 /usr/local/bin/lame -b16 --noshort "/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/$1.wav" "/var/www/html/asterisk/calls/$1.mp3"
```